# Why store API keys outside of one's application?

Tags: php, security, environment-variables, constants, api-key

I'm confused on the security benefit of storing one's API keys for another app outside of their own application.

If someone can read your application files why can't they read files such as your php.ini, server config files, etc?

Can someone explain this given following directory structure (only meant to be illustrative):

Inside application:

```
root/.../html/application/keys/somekeyfile.php with API keys defined as constant variables, e.g., define('API_key', 'xxxx');
```

Outside application

```
root/../php/php.ini //with API keys defined as environment variables, e.g., $_ENV['API_key']
```

Comment: If you misconfigure your webserver, then somebody might get access to your php script files below the webserver root; but won't get access to files outside the webserver root

Comment: thanks @MarkBaker, in what circumstances might one misconfigure their webserver? file upload where permissions are changing? other examples? perhaps that is an answer?

Comment: Consider the number of people asking questions on SO who've not configured their webservers to execute PHP, so the script is shown in its entirety

Comment: can you clarify? i'm not following...

Comment: If you don't configure your webserver to parse php files, then it will display php files (showing the actual code) and if passwords are stored in those php files, those passwords will be visible... but only php files that are under the webserver root will be visible

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have a webserver - linux, in this case (I'm basing this file structure off of an Amazon EC2 "Amazon Linux" instance).

**The server:**

Web services (Apache, php, etc.) are installed and configured here:

```
/etc
```

Understanding linux file structure is largely out of scope here, but you can research that on your own time. Web instances (html files, document roots, etc.) are configured in httpd.conf:

```
/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`
```

By default, document roots are configured to point to an entirely different directory tree (or could even be volume, in certain instances):

```
/var/www
```

You can of course change this behavior, but out of the box, web document root files exist in a separate directory tree from your server config.

**The security model:**

Web document roots are inherently secure because they do not allow you to traverse further up the document tree. For example, if you have a document root for a vhost here (and configured properly):

```
/var/www/html/example.com
```

When you visit http://example.com, the web document root (`/`) points to that folder. You cannot, from the web server, traverse backward to `../html` like you could if you were browsing in the console.

*There are of course exceptions to this rule* in that you could use `file_get_contents()` in php to open files elsewhere, or you could configure your vhosts incorrectly, but *again*, out of the box, this is the way things are.

**Compromised:**

A hacker maliciously gains control of your site at the document root level. Let's say they have access to `index.php` now or even `includes/api_keys.php`. If you stored your API keys there -- they're now in the hands of the attacker.

But if you store them instead in `php.ini`, the attacker only has limited access to your site's document root -- not the `/etc` directory, and thus your API keys remain secured.

(Keep in mind that if your server is compromised through root/ssh/shell access, you're not safe either way).

**Conclusion / tl;dr:**

There is an entire world of security best practice, but this should get you started with a basic understanding of separating configuration from documents/scripts. In short: keep your document root separate from your config files, so that if your document root is compromised, your server configuration remains secure.

Comment: hi @remus thanks, the thing I don't understand is **how** someone would gain control of a site at the document root level vs. if they ssh into. Can you explain in your answer mechanistically how people do that? I'll be happy to accept your answer with that addition.

Comment: There's more than enough here for the answer to be accepted. Perhaps @remus doesn't want to give malintenders search result fodder.